# Dynamic CasperJS loop terminates at random iterations

Tags: javascript, casperjs

This code expands on the dynamic.js script. The dynamic.js runs like this: `start`, `then`, `run`, and then the `run` callback is the dynamic `loop`. That runs fine. My code doesn't want to loop at the end of the `run` callback, it wants to loop in the middle, so that I can run more code afterwards. So it's `start`, `then`, `loop`, `then`, `run`. It seems that `casper` is not waiting for my `loop` to finish before exiting. The loop terminates at different points every time that it runs, and I never see the `"after dynamic loop"` echo out. Here is some sample output (it ends anywhere between 2 and 8 loops, usually), and then the code:

Output:

```
start main
start dynamic loop
0
Something.
1
Something.
2
Something.
3
Something.
4
Something.
5
Something.
```

Code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var limit = 10;
var i = 0;

// dynamic loop
var loop = function () {
    if (i < limit) {
        this.echo(i);
        this.start("http://www.something.com", function() {
            this.echo(this.evaluate(function () { return document.body.innerText; }));
        });
        i++;
        this.run(loop);
    } else {
        this.echo("dynamic loop done");
        this.exit();
    }
}

// main flow
casper.start('http://www.something.com', function() {
    this.echo("start main");
});

casper.then(function () {
    casper.start().then(function() {
        this.echo("start dynamic loop");
    });
    casper.run(loop);
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.echo("after dynamic loop");
})

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `casper.start` and `casper.run` only once in your script. However, you can use them. If you do you run into "undefined" behavior if you nest them in another control flow. I find it is best to use `casper.thenOpen` and `casper.then` as a replacement for `casper.start` and `casper.run`:

```
// dynamic loop
var loop = function () {
    if (i < limit) {
        this.echo(i);
        i++;
        this.thenOpen("http://www.something.com", function() {
            this.echo(this.evaluate(function () { return document.body.innerText; }));
        });
        this.then(loop);
    } else {
        this.echo("dynamic loop done");
    }
}

// main flow
casper.start('http://www.something.com', function() {
    this.echo("start main");
});

casper.then(loop);

casper.then(function () {
    this.echo("after dynamic loop");
})

casper.run();
```

You may have multiple `casper` instances in one script, but then you would need to synchronize them somehow.

Your script may need a little fix without refactoring. Just remove `this.exit();` from loop. You exit prematurely. But I still strongly suggest that you refactor your script.

Comment: This makes sense. I think the lesson learned here is that if you want to make Casperjs dynamic based on page results, then you have to use callbacks after `run` is finished. My example code doesn't show that, but that's what my goal is. On first glance, the dynamic.js code looks like it's nesting `start`, but it's just callbacks. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If `casper.run` is finished then the script terminates. If you break out of the CasperJS control flow then you have to `wait` alongside of the broken of flow. This is usually not necessary. Btw, what is **dynamic.js**? Is this some script that you found on the web or something you wrote?

Comment: It's a script in the sample scripts folder that comes with casper.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that those also exist. Although this is done from the CasperJS creator, I think this is bad style to use `start` and especially `run` multiple times.